# How to use EMRFS S3-optimized committer without EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I want to use EMRFS S3-optimized committer locally without EMR cluster.
I have set "fs.s3a.impl" = "com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem" instead of "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem" and following exception raised:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found
```

Tried to use following packages from maven without any success:

- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.12.71
- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:1.12.70

Comment: how did you try to use this packages, did you add them as dependencies ? Please provide the command line you used to submit the job as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but using EMRFS, including the S3-optimized committer, is not possible off of EMR.

EMRFS is not an open source package, nor is the library available in Maven Central. This is why the class is not found when you try to add aws-java-sdk-emr as a dependency; that package is solely for the AWS Java SDK client package used when interfacing with the EMR service (e.g., to create clusters).